# Can't redirect if not logged in React Token auth

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this app, frontend is React and backend is Laravel. I did the auth system using Laravel Passport. When the user is logged in, I save the token in local storage. If the user is not logged in, I want to automatically redirect to `/login`. Basically the user can't do anything if it's not logged in. I tried this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/login" exact component={FormularAuth} />
        {
          isAuthenticated ? (
            <React.Fragment>
              *ALL OTHER ROUTES ARE HERE, AND IF LOGGED IN, IT WORKS*
            </React.Fragment>
           ) : ( 
                   window.location = '/login')
               )
         }
</BrowserRouter>
```

It send's me to the `/login` page, but it keeps refreshing, and I can't login or anything. What is the problem here?

Comment: try `<Redirect to='/login' />`

Comment: Now I get this error: `app.js:79223 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: what's in Login?

Comment: @JuniusL. It's just a form with two fields and a button. If I simply do `/login` I can access it, so that's not the problem

Comment: can you post the render method containing this code

Answer (score 0):

react router v4 supports use of `PrivateRoute`.

```
// create a private route, if user is not logged in redirect to login page
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated() === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
)
```

Use it like a normal route and check authentication in the private route.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/login" exact component={FormularAuth} />
  <PrivateRoute path='/private' component={Private} />
</BrowserRouter>
```